# Cannot understand defproject?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

New linux (centos7), new lighttable, new lein, new project:

> clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: defproject in this context, compiling:(/home/zzz/nnn/lighttable/project.clj:1:1)

This is the project:

```
(defproject lighttable "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    :description "FIXME: write description"
    :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
    :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
              :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]])
```

After some years of trying clojure, with a project that is in prod. (not this one, of course): am I missing something?

Comment: are you trying to run your project.clj in any way or have you made it part of the source?  the file is not supposed to be run directly (basically) but `lein` picks it up as a description what to do.

Comment: Suddenly, it ran without any apparent reason.

Answer (score 4):

Could you try it again from a clean directory?  It seems to be working for me:

```
~/tmp9 > lein new app lighttable
Generating a project called lighttable based on the 'app' template.
~/tmp9 > cd lighttable 
~/tmp9/lighttable > lein run
Hello, World!
~/tmp9/lighttable > cat project.clj 
(defproject lighttable "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot lighttable.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

I noticed you have two `:url` entries and are missing some other stuff.  Did you create it by using the command `lein new app lighttable` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using IntelliJ + Cursive like I am, then this will occur if your run/debug configuration points to the `project.clj` file instead of `core.clj` for a Clojure Application configuration with `How to run it` set to `Run with Leiningen`